# Use MUX Player (Video) in Angular 14/15

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gorilla

Mux is a video API service that has its own player: [MUX Player](https://www.mux.com/player)

I am wanting to use this npm package in Angular 14/15 by importing it into a specific component only. The js should only be loaded when this component is loaded.

### Import

The two methods of using the service are:

1. via a direct `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mux/mux-player"></script>` import in the HTML (which I can do in angular's `index.html` file. This does however mean that the script is loaded for everyone, which is not what I want.
2. npm Package `@mux/mux-player`

### Usage

Add the code to a component's HTML where the script or npm package has been imported.

```
<mux-player
stream-type="on-demand"
playback-id="FuJSYrK0014ec2LPnm11bzC2MAySAQPqA"
metadata-video-title="Tea and Cookies"
metadata-user-id="user-24601"
/>
```

Making sure to also include `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` in the module (or standalone component).

### Problem

Angular can be a bit weird about untyped packages. I *think* that this package uses typescript, but in any case, importing the npm package gives me plenty of errors. Essentially, it's not being loaded because Angular is tree-shaking it out when I am not using the imported class in the components' ts. This means that on load, I am seeing:
`Cannot find module '../../../types/mux' or its corresponding type declarations` and `Property 'error' in type 'MuxVideoElement' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CustomVideoElement<HTMLVideoElement>'. Type 'MediaError' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaError': MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED, MEDIA_ERR_DECODE, MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK, MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`

### What I've tried

1. To confirm that the `<script>` import and HTML code work together, I imported the script into the `index.html`, and this removed all errors and the player loaded fine.
2. I have tried importing the npm package `import MuxPlayerElement from "@mux/mux-player";`, and added `declare module "@mux/mux-player";` to the `typings.d.ts`.
3. Import the package into the component, and tried to declare the @ViewChild template ref as a MuxPlayerElement, to get around any tree-shaking.

There is an Angular demo where it says "This player? It's an open book." at https://www.mux.com/player, however, this results in the error `Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "mux-player"`. Easy solution to this is to close the tag with `</mux-player>` rather than `.../>`

Answer (score 1):

## Update!

**Mux addressed angular support in `1.9.0`**

https://docs.mux.com/guides/player/releases#190

Instructions for usage:

1. `npm install @mux/mux-player`
2. add `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to module (or standalone component)
3. add `import "@mux/mux-player"` to the target component imports
4. Use as documented `<mux-player ...></mux-player>`